# Python - Global variable struggle

Tags: python, local-variables

It might be rediculous but I couldn't get my head around the use of global variables in Python. It throws me syntax errors for the use of the keyword

```
global
```

even though, I looked it up exactly that way in the documentation.

I know the code is clumsy for its repetative use of global variables. Anyway, how to use them correctly?

```
import random

r_list = []

my_list =[3,4,45,7,23,33]
match_list=[]
iteration = 0
number_matches = 0

def fill_random_list():
    for i in range(7):
        # print (random.randint(1,49))
        r_list.append(random.randint(1,49))


def return_matches(lista, listb):
    # print set(lista).intersection(listb)
    return set(lista).intersection(listb)


def return_number_matches(l_matches):
    if l_matches:
        return len(l_matches)


def draw_lottery():
    while global number_matches  < 5:'''
                                     File "C:/Lottery.py", line 27
                                     while global number_matches  < 5:
                                                ^
                                     SyntaxError: invalid syntax'''
        global r_list = []
        global match_list = []
        fill_random_list()
        match_list=return_matches(r_list, my_list)
        global number_matches=(return_number_matches(global match_list))
        global iteration+=1
        if number_matches > 4:
            print (str(global iteration) + ';' + str(global number_matches))


def iterate(number):
    for i in enumerate(range(number),1):
        print('Round: ' + str(i[0]))
        draw_lottery()


def main():
    iterate(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: How did you find out about the `global` keyword and what did your source say about using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't annotate every use of a global variable with `global`. All you need to do is write `global var1, var2` in your function before modifying the variables.

If you're only reading from them you don't need to use `global`. You only need it if you're assigning to them.

```
def draw_lottery():
    global number_matches, r_list, match_list, number_matches, iteration

    while number_matches < 5:
        r_list     = []
        match_list = []

        fill_random_list()

        match_list     = return_matches(r_list, my_list)
        number_matches = return_number_matches(match_list)

        iteration += 1

        if number_matches > 4:
            print(str(iteration) + ';' + str(number_matches))
```

As a matter of good style, avoid using global variables. It's hard to keep track of program state when many functions share the same variables. It's better to use parameters and `return` values instead, whenever possible.

Comment: > " It's better to use parameters and return values instead" - or use a class if the shared state has to be maintained between functions calls.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your code is quite simple
if you want to modify a global variable inside a function you need first to refer to it explicitly, how?
be including the line

```
global variable_name
```

in your function code, this should occur before reading or modifying this variable